# How to change span position automatically, if some text added before spanned text in EditText?

Tags: android, spannablestring, spannable, spanned, android-editable

Am creating an application in which edittext adds style span to certain positions of text

```
editable.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), start, start+replacement.length(),Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

My issue is that if user adds, some text or white space before the spanned text style will removed, how to avoid that ?

```
    int SPAN_COMPOSING = 256;
    int SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE = 33;
    int SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE = 34;
    int SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE = 17;
    int SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE = 18;
    int SPAN_INTERMEDIATE = 512;
    int SPAN_MARK_MARK = 17;
    int SPAN_MARK_POINT = 18;
    int SPAN_PARAGRAPH = 51;
    int SPAN_POINT_MARK = 33;
    int SPAN_POINT_MARK_MASK = 51;
    int SPAN_POINT_POINT = 34;
    int SPAN_PRIORITY = 16711680;
    int SPAN_PRIORITY_SHIFT = 16;
    int SPAN_USER = -16777216;
    int SPAN_USER_SHIFT = 24;
```

Which type will i need to use in my case ?

Comment: Use TextWatcher. You will get a callback for everytime your text has changed. use setSpan there.

Comment: can you read my question again ?

Comment: I Know this maybe a bit late but you should first make sure you are spanning till editable.Length .EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE Is the best if you don't want the span to extend either left or right.However this problem can occur because of the auto-correction if you are spanning part of a word which is just stupid .You can disable the autocorrection via .   `android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences|textShortMessage|textVisiblePassword"` in the EditText XML

Answer (score -1):

You can use like below code.

```
editable.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // here is your code to change position
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }

        });
```

Comment: can you please elaborate it or if it is possible send me before after images of it.